# Leer y escribir objetos en un fichero y añadirlos a un modelo

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo que realizar una actividad en la que guardo objetos en un archivo. Por lo que he leído en internet, debe tener la extensión **.obj**. Luego tengo que leer los objetos de ese archivo y añadirlos a un modelo personalizado y mostrarlos en una lista. La clase se llama **Contactos** y tiene implementada la interfaz **Serializable**. El modelo funciona correctamente, pero a la hora de leer el objeto del archivo devuelve un `EOFException`. Todo esto en un `JFrame`.

Escritura del objeto:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
oos.writeObject(
    new Contactos(
        txtNombre.getText(),
        txtApellidos.getText(),
        txtEmail.getText(),
        Integer.parseInt(txtMovil.getText()),
        Integer.parseInt(txtFijo.getText())
    )
);
oos.close();
actualizarModelo();
```

El método `actualizarModelo();`:

```
public void actualizarModelo() {
    try{
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        Object obj;
        while((obj = ois.readObject()) instanceof Contactos) {
            modelo.add((Contactos)ois.readObject()); //Aquí es donde falla
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

La excepción que lanza:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2626)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1321)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at Contactos.GestionarContactos.actualizarModelo(GestionarContactos.java:373)
at Contactos.GestionarContactos.guardarActionPerformed(GestionarContactos.java:283)
at Contactos.GestionarContactos.access$300(GestionarContactos.java:15)
at Contactos.GestionarContactos$5.actionPerformed(GestionarContactos.java:180)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: El error lo tienes en el método actualizar?

Comment: Sí, el error estaba ahí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple vista me parece que lees el objeto dos veces. Prueba esto:

```
 while((obj = ois.readObject()) instanceof Contactos) {
            modelo.add((Contactos)obj); //obj ya fue leído en el while
        }
```

En cuanto a evitar excepción después del while, más que evitar que salte la excepción al leer más allá del fin del archivo, lo que puedes hacer es neutralizar esa excepción en concreto finalizando el método de lectura:

```
public void actualizarModelo() {
    try{
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        Object obj;
        while((obj = ois.readObject()) instanceof Contactos) {
            modelo.add((Contactos)obj);
        }
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        return;              // excepción por fin de archivo: salimos sin problemas
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // otras excepciones que no son fin de archivo
    }
}
```

Comment: Pues sí, era eso, ahora tengo que controlar que cuando salga del while no se meta en el catch, muchas gracias.